# ModuleNotFoundError when attempting to import from outside of directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import, relative-path

I'm working on a Flask app and attempting to run my test file but unable to do so. My current app structure is:

```
Project
── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── model.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── img
│   │   ├── js
│   │   └── uploads
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── client
│   │   │   ├── client-base.html
│   │   │   ├── client-inventory.html
│   │   │   ├── client-login.html
│   │   │   ├── client-macros.html
│   │   │   ├── client-main.html
│   │   │   └── client-signup.html
│   │   └── user
│   │       ├── user-base.html
│   │       ├── user-macros.html
│   │       └── user-main.html
│   └── views
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── client.py
│       └── user.py
├── config.py
├── run.py
└── tests
    └── test_user_model.py
```

when I attempt to run `from app.models import User` in `test_user_model.py` it raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`. I've tried editing the import statement countless different ways but it still raises an error in every case (`from ..app import models` is out of scope, `import app` and similar imports also don't work.)

Comment: What folder are you running this from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `__init__.py` in your `tests` directory. The empty `__init__.py` will turn that directory into a package. Then you can use this line in your `test_user_model.py`:

```
from app.models import User
```

See details in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: Can you please clarify where to "use" that import statement, and how `__init__.py` works?

Comment: @colllin Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `app` in your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Are you sure? Importing a module from outside the directory doesn't seem that difficult, I've seen it done a number of time previously without having to edit `PYTHONPATH` - even in the [official flask practice application](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/examples/flaskr/tests/test_flaskr.py) the tests import the app by just calling `from flaskr import flaskr`

Comment: You can either add the module to the python path by exporting the environment variable or do that in the code.

Comment: But I'm confused as to why I would need to alter the python path at all when other projects are able to import modules from different directories without a problem?

Comment: You can do the change locally in the tests scripts.